# How to change duplicate rows to unique values in mysql databse

Tags: mysql, doc

I have a database table with about 1M records. I need to find all duplicate names in this table and make them unique.

### Id   Name

1    A
2    A
3    B
4    C
5    C
Should be changed to...

### Id   Name

1    A
2    A-1
3    B
4    C
5    C-1
Is there an effective way of doing this with a mysql query or procedure?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: UPDATE    table_x AS upd
    SET   upd.Name = CONCAT(upd.Name, '-', upd.Id)
    WHERE upd.id IN(
                    SELECT    sel.id
                        FROM  table_x AS sel
                        WHERE sel.Name = upd.Name
                          AND sel.Id != upd.Id
                 ); not working for me

Answer (score 1):

I needed to do something similar to a table I was just working on. I needed a unique URL field but the previous keepers of the data did not keep these constraints. The key was to create a temp table.

I used this response here to help: [MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause#answer-45498)

Take note that it doesn't perform well, but then again if you only need to run it once on a database to clean a table then it shouldn't be so bad.

```
UPDATE `new_article` `upd`
SET `upd`.`url` = CONCAT(`upd`.`url`, '-', `upd`.`id`)
WHERE `upd`.`url` IN(
    SELECT `url` FROM (
        SELECT `sel`.`url` FROM `new_article` `sel`
        GROUP BY `sel`.`url` HAVING count(`sel`.`id`) > 1
    ) as `temp_table`
);
```